# C code giving error in VS Code. "crt2.o: file not recognized"

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am running a simple C code of Hello World in VS Code but it is giving Error:

> PS D:\New\C> cd "d:\New\C" ; if ($?) { gcc Hello.c -o Hello } ; if ($?) { .\Hello }
> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../crt2.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Error Code]

I tried to find a solution on web but all of them suggested to save the file before running but I am having the same error even after saving the file.

Comment: One thing is you didn't follow the official VSCode c++ tutorial. The reason I say that is you have a very old version of MinGW installed (and not one with gcc-13.2) instead of the one VSCode told you to install: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: The second problem is your compiler appears to be corrupted in some way that it can't recognize its own files.